# ffmpeg-normalize with id3v2 tags

Tags: command-line, audio, ffmpeg

I'm running fmpeg-normalize in the Windows command line on an audio with cover, but the command to generate the output file with the cover is not recognized, it only works, with the c:v copy option. With other options it doesn't. ffmpeg-normalize does not recognize id3v2 information.

How do I output the cover using the ffmpeg-normalize facility?

Works:
`ffmpeg-normalize "input.mp3" -nt ebu -t -10 -tp -0.5 -c:a mp3 -b:a 320k -ar 44100 --extra-output-options "-c:v copy" -o "output_LUFS.mp3" -p`

Doesn’t work:
`ffmpeg-normalize "input.mp3" -nt ebu -t -10 -tp -0.5 -c:a mp3 -b:a 320k -ar 44100 --extra-output-options "-c:v copy" "-id3v2_version 3" "-metadata:s:v title=""Album cover""" "-metadata:s:v comment=""Cover (front)""" -o "output_LUFS.mp3" -p`

`ffmpeg-normalize: error: unrecognized arguments: -id3v2_version 3 -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)"`

Answer (score 1):

The above command did't kept cover for me when I tried to normalize mp3 files, but still helped a lot to copy the idv3 tags. Thanks!

I decided to do multiple steps: extract the cover, normalize the mp3 file, reinsert cover.

Used this to extract to cover:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "input.mp3" -an -c:v mjpeg -vf scale=320:-1 ./tmp/cover.png
```

Some explanation:

- an - means do not copy the audio stream
- c:v - copies the video stream, in my case the cover
- vf sacle=320:-1 - will scale the cover art to 320px while keeping aspect ratio

Next step was to normalize the audio file:

```
ffmpeg-normalize  "$i" -nt ebu -c:a mp3 -b:a 224k --extra-output-options "-id3v2_version 3" -o "./tmp/input.mp3" -p
```

I have removed here to options which were not needed. Kept to bitrate to 224k.

The final step was to insert back to cover:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "./tmp/input.mp3" -i "./tmp/cover.png" -c copy -map 0 -map 1 -metadata:s:v title=""Album\ cover"" -metadata:s:v comment=""Cover\ \(front\)"" "./normalized/output.mp3"
```

This commands takes 2 input streams the pure normalized mp3 data and the cover image. Copies them together into final file located in the "normalized" folder, and also adds metadata to the video stream, saying this is the cover.

In summary I have created a small script which does it for all mp3 in a folder, but does no error checking:

```
mkdir ./tmp
mkdir ./normalized
for i in *.mp3
do
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -i "$i" -an -c:v mjpeg -vf scale=320:-1 ./tmp/cover.png
ffmpeg-normalize  "$i" -nt ebu -c:a mp3 -b:a 224k --extra-output-options "-id3v2_version 3" -o "./tmp/$i" -p
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -i "./tmp/$i" -i "./tmp/cover.png" -c copy -map 0 -map 1 -metadata:s:v title=""Album\ cover"" -metadata:s:v comment=""Cover\ \(front\)"" "./normalized/$i"
rm ./tmp/cover.png
rm "./tmp/$i"
done
```

Hope you find it useful.
Apulai

Answer (score 0):

Error was in the configuration of the command.

The correct command is:

To normalize file without cover art:

```
ffmpeg-normalize "input_without_cover" -nt ebu -t -10 -tp -1.5 -c:a mp3 -b:a 320k -ar 44100 -o "output_normalized_without_cover" -p
```

To normalize file with cover art:

```
ffmpeg-normalize "input_with_cover" -nt ebu -t -10 -tp -1.5 -c:a mp3 -b:a 320k -ar 44100 --extra-output-options "-c:v copy -id3v2_version 3 -metadata:s:v title=""Album cover"" -metadata:s:v comment=""Cover (front)""" -o "output_normalized_with_cover" -p
```

This second command will add the cover art of the input file to the normalized output file.